# css hover show separate hidden element

Tags: html, css, menu

I’m trying to make some content show when I hover over the link, using only css - can you look into this for me. I think I’m on the right path just need some clear directions please  thank you for your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/JOSBORNE_/achmfszv/#&togetherjs=0o94SRwPsi

I’m trying to re-create this type of effect as seen in this tutorial:

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-trendy-flat-style-nav-menu-in-css

minimal code example:

```css
#Link1 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -440px 0 0 9%;
  width: 80%;
  display: none;
}

.Link1:hover #Link1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuforspecials">

  <li class="Link1"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>

</div>

<li class="current" id="Link1">
  <h2>Offer Heading 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tristique in lacus ut vulputate. Nullam rhoncus, dolor quis euismod.</p>
</li>
<li id="Link2">
  <h2>Offer Heading 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tristique in lacus ut vulputate. Nullam rhoncus, dolor quis euismod.</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Post your [mcve] in your question please. Don't force us to go to another site to see your code. It belongs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very basic problem, hover animations can only affect elements inside or near the anchor tag. Plain css will not allow you to hover over a link and affect an element further down the page if it doesn't meet the aforementioned proximity requirement.

Here is a basic example of what can be done.

```css
.content{
  display: none;
}

.menuforspecials a:hover + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuforspecials">

  <li class="Link1"><a href="">Link 1</a>
    <div id="Link1" class="content">
      <h2>Offer Heading 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tristique in lacus ut vulputate. Nullam rhoncus, dolor quis euismod.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a>
    <div id="Link2" class="content">
      <h2>Offer Heading 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tristique in lacus ut vulputate. Nullam rhoncus, dolor quis euismod.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>

</div>
```